# How to check for any matching cells in two columns for excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an excel file containing multiple sheets. The first sheet named = " Main " is what I am working on and the sheet named = " Data " contains the back data, using which I am building a symmetric matrix. Eg showed in the image for both.

I want to check if the intersection cells in the "Main" sheet have any matching values in their respective columns in sheet "Data" and get 1 (if yes) or 0(if no matching cell value) found.

For eg, if in "Main" Sheet I am at Column E and Row 4 ie E4, so if want look for the column named as the header of column E and row 4 in the "Data" sheet and check if any of their cells have matching contents.

Link for sample data : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W5Nj91lVUt0NAm_h6KkONucoy2sXMGjJ3z-Tl1K1QhY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so you would search value of EI in "Main" sheet in column B of "Data" sheet?

Comment: No, the "Data" sheet contains data column-wise. It has a header that corresponds to a name of a player and the Main sheets contain player names as Columns and rows to find if they have played together. So, for every cell in "Main sheet," I have to go through the data in the "Data" sheet to check if they any common matches ( which is a unique ODI number). If they have any common match I enter 1 in that cell of the "Main" sheet 0 otherwise.

Comment: Sounds like a COUNTIFS but without data example, can't assure it

Comment: I have added the sample data now, you can refer to link in question.

Comment: Nice, thanks, but still not clear. So following your example, cell E4 in "Main Sheet" is empty. Column name is `Krishnamachari Srikkanth`. That value does not exist in Sheet "Data" so then return 0?

Comment: That was just for saying basis. If you take the above sample data into account lets say I want to fill cell F7 ( col header = Maninder Singh, row name = Chetan Sharma). If they have any common matches among themselves in the "Data" sheet then the value in that F7 cell should be 1 otherwise 0. So, I have to read the data from the columns named "Maninder Singh" and "Chetan Sharma" in the "Data" sheet and accordingly print the output in "Main" sheet with 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to accomplish it, would be to use named ranges.  You can name every column on the Data sheet with the name of the player (without spaces - as I have done so on your file).

To calculate how many ODIs any two players have in common you can simply multiply their respective ranges (columns), for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(indirect(substitute(A6," ",""))=TRANSPOSE(indirect(substitute(G1," ",""))))
```

The indirect function resolves to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ManinderSingh=TRANSPOSE(ChetanSharma))
```

And gives you the total of matches those two played together:
[image]

It would be possible to do it without the named ranges, instead looking up the player names dynamically but that would make a pretty messy and complicated formula (at least the way I have attempted it).  Setting up named ranges might take you a few extra minutes but it's a far more elegant solution in my opinion.

Comment: Hi Michal, thank you for the answer. I have added the full data to the same sheet and was doing the calculation after changing the row name in the "Data" sheet as you mentioned. The formula worked well for the cells that were there in the sample (on which you had provided the code), but for the newly added columns in the "Data" sheet, it's giving an error. Error (for say G5 says): "Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is "KapilDev". It is not a valid cell/range reference ". But KapilDev is there in the "Data" Sheet, added by me recently. Maybe you can the sheet and let me know .

Comment: @VinayDalal - please read my response carefully.  For each player you need to define a named range - go to Data and Named Ranges and see how I have done it for the sample you have posted.  You need to create a named range for each player on each column.

Comment: Oh got it @Michal. Thanks a lot. Didn't know about the named ranges option.